# How to listen to changes in all mongoDB collection

Tags: meteor

I'm writing a meteor app,
I would like to write an observer which will listen to changes on a remote mongoDB,
Though I would like to write somthing generic which will listen to all Collections and will send the old value and new value. I mean:

```
var DBCollections = new Meteor.Collection.getall();  -> whats the right way to do this?

var cursor = DBCollection.find();


// watch the cursor for changes
var handle = cursor.observe({
  added: function (object) {
    var result = Meteor.http.post(
       "http://localhost:8080",
       { params: { command: "add_object", value: object} } );


   },
  changed: function (object) {
    oldValue = ???   -> how can I get it?
     var result = Meteor.http.post(
    "http://localhost:8080",
        { params: {command:"modify_object",oldValue: oldValue,newValue: object}} );


       },
  removed: function (object) {
      var result = Meteor.http.post(
     "http://localhost:8080",
     { params: { command: "remove_object",value: object } } );

   }
});
```

so my qustions are like this:

1. how can I get all collections and observe changes on them?
2. When object modified how can I get the old value?

Comment: You could use something like [meteor collection behaviour](https://github.com/Sewdn/meteor-collection-behaviours). You can use it to define **hooks** on your different **collections**.

Comment: writing a ddp erlang client is the answer.
https://meteorhacks.com/introduction-to-ddp.html
https://github.com/st23am/philae/

Comment: https://meteorhacks.com/discover-meteor-ddp-in-realtime.html